# Cannot compare http request response using Result

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have a class that defines a send function to make an http request that returns a Result type.
Result is a system-defined type basically is a generic enum that contains 2 possible values: .success(...) and .failure(...)

```
public typealias ResultCallback<Value> = (Result<Value, Error>) -> Void
class NetworkManager: NetworkManagerType{

    func send(_ requestUrl: URL, completion: @escaping 
    ResultCallback<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)>)  // equivalent to (Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>)
 ...
}
```

In my unit test I would be able to compare expected Result objects with the actual Result returned by the send function.

```
func testFailureResponse() {
        // PREPARE MOCK DATA
        session.mockHttpResponse = mockFailedHttpResponse
        session.mockData = mockData
        session.mockError = NetworkManagerError.httpRequestFailed(response: mockFailedHttpResponse, data: mockData)

        // MAKE REQUEST
        netManager.send(myTaxyUrl, completion:  {  (result: Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>) -> ()  in
              let expectedResult = Result<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data), Error>.failure(  NetworkManagerError.httpRequestFailed(response: mockFailedHttpResponse, data: mockData))

              XCTAssertTrue( expectedResult == result) // !! Errors here!!
              ...
}
```

The errors are:

1. ' (Self.Type) -> (Self, Self) -> Bool'
   requires that '(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)' conform to
   'Equatable'
2. Type '(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)' does not conform to
   protocol 'Equatable'

It seems that saying the tuple does not conform to protocol Equatable, still it is possible to equate my tuples:

```
let t1 = (response: mockFailedHttpResponse, data: mockData)
let t2 = (response: mockFailedHttpResponse, data: mockData)
print(t1 == t2) // true
```

So, given that swift doesn't allow to enforce Equatability on a tuple type ( because a tuple it is not a named type), how can I compare actual and expected results?

Comment: Why not simply do two asserts - first assert that `expectedResult.response == result.response` and then assert that `data` parameters are equal.

Comment: @Losiowaty Because if the request fails the value of the Result enum wold be Result.failure(Error) so there would be no result.response and the test would crash. Remember that Result is an enum. so its value can be either  .failure or .success